# Unable to fill object with polymer databinding 2.X

Tags: javascript, input, data-binding, polymer-2.x

I'm on something simple but frustrating, I have a bunch of (paper-)input to fill a form, but i'm totally unable to read the data from those.

```js
//Here is the declaration of the property:
static get propreties() {
    return {
        formData: {
            type: Object,
            value: {}
        }
    }
}

//And here is the piece of code logging the actual state of the element.
_buildBody(){
    console.log("form data : ", this.formData);

}
```

```html
<!-- Here are my inputs -->
<paper-input label="Nom de l'alerte" always-float-label value="{{formData.alertName::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="Résumé" always-float-label value="{{formData.summary::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="Continent" always-float-label value="{{formData.continent::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="Pays" always-float-label value="{{formData.country::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input  label="Ville" always-float-label value="{{formData.city::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-textarea char-counter maxlength="800" label="Description" always-float-label value="{{formData.desc::input}}" required></paper-textarea>
<div align="center"style="margin-top:20px;">
    <paper-button raised on-tap="_buildBody" class="primary" disabled={{disState}}>Proposer</paper-button>
```

What is frustrating is that a I do the exact same thing on another element and it work like a charm.

```js
//Working declaration of property
static get properties() {
  return {
      formData: {
          type: Object,
          value: {}
      }
  }
}
//Working piece of code for logging the form data
_testButton(evt){
    console.log(this.formData);
}
```

```html
<!--Working input -->
<paper-input label="Username" auto-validate pattern="[a-zA-Z_0-9]{6,15}" value="{{formData.username::input}}"></paper-input>
<paper-input id="input"label="Password" type="password" auto-validate pattern="[a-zA-Z_0-9@!]{6,15}" value="{{formData.password::input}}"></paper-input>
```

So can someone understand why is this thing not working ? :/ 
Have a nice day everyone!

Comment: You misspelled `properties` as `propreties`. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: You just saved the day sir :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to use value="{{formData.alertName}}"

Comment: It might be but I've got used to it